# Showing numeric keyboard issue in IOS , Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have used input type = "number" for displaying only a numeric keyboard. It works fine in android, but not in iOS. Is there any other way to do that?

What I actually want is an input box that only allows 0 to 9 and the max length of input is 1.

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
<input type="number" maxlength="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern: `pattern="[0-9]*"`

So: `<input type="number" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" />`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d*">
```

Or you can use a plugin
https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ion-digit-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use  type="tel"

```
<input type="tel" />
```